# Cant get my form to submit

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have created a form which appears when a button is clicked. This is achieved using Jquery .append

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#adddiet").click(function () {
$('#newbox').append("<div class='span3 diet'><div class='diet-content'><h3>Add a diet</h3></div><div class='content-text2'><form action='sendDietContent.php' method='post'><strong>Title:</strong> <input type='text' name='title'><br><strong>Description:</strong><input type='text' name='description'><br></div><div class='diet-button'><input type='submit'></div></form></div>"); });  });
```

However when the submit button is clicked nothing happens?

Here is the php that its supposed to call:

```
<?php
require 'DB/connect.php';
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO ContentDiet (title, description, dateAdded)
VALUES ('$_POST[title]', '$_POST[description]', '$_POST[$date]')"; 
?>
```

Comment: Press F12 and check in your console what is the error. There must be some kind of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html code is mal-formed. The form tag starts in a div which is at a lower level than the submit button so the submit button doesn't get included in the form. Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#adddiet").click(function () {
$('#newbox').append("<div class='span3 diet'><form action='sendDietContent.php' method='post'><div class='diet-content'><h3>Add a diet</h3></div><div class='content-text2'><strong>Title:</strong> <input type='text' name='title'><br><strong>Description:</strong><input type='text' name='description'><br></div><div class='diet-button'><input type='submit'></div></form></div>"); });  });
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, much appreciated